# React functional component update state by key

Tags: reactjs, react-state

Within a Component Class, I found it easy to create one handler that did a lot of heavy lifting for form inputs. By matching the name of the input to the this.state.key, I was able to update specific state variables with the same onChange handler:

```
handleCheck = event => {
  this.setState({ [event.target.name] : event.target.value})
};
```

Now that I'm using functional components and I've flattened my state out, I'd like to be able to do with same thing instead of writing a function for handleNameOfEveryInputOnMyForm.  Is my only option to put state variables I need to access this way into an object? And then go through all the headaches of updating deep state variables?

Comment: Do you actually want a deep update? It seems like you want an object with a single level.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [functional update pattern](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state), where you supply a function to the setter of `useState` instead of providing a value directly.

This allows you to access the current state and then overwrite the object with a specific key. You can do this with the help of the [object spread operator `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

You can instantiate your ground state with the `useState()` hook with an empty object.

```js
const [state, setState] = useState({});

function handleCheck = (e) => {
  setState(previousState => {
    return {
      // Spread the previous state
      ...previousState,

      // Overwrite specific key with new value
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    };
  });
};
```

You can even further simplify it if you [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) `e.target` and also [enclose the returned object in parenthesis to take advantage of the implicit return of arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#function_body):

```js
function handleCheck = (e) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  setState(previousState => ({
    ...previousState,
    [name]: value,
  }));
};
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! Would your solution be dependent on me having declared an object state variable named state and then added all of my data to that object? I believe that's how I'm reading it and ultimately I could do that but was hoping to not have to mess with objects at the top level of my state. Thank you for the tip on functional update pattern, that'll definitely save me some time.

Comment: That will require you to use the useState hook, but you can simply instantiate it with an empty object. I'll update my answer in a bit.